# Json foreach to make custom array for fusion chart

Tags: json

json each loop to make an array in some specific format is not working in fusion chart

if generate code copied from console it works fine, i tired more than dozen search in stack overflow

```
var data_ChartStores = {
                categories: [
                                {
                                                category: [
                                                                {label: 'week_22'}, {label: 'week_23'}, {label: 'week_24'}, {label: 'week_25'}, 
                                                ]
                                }
                ],
                dataset: [
                                {
                                                seriesname: "Store 38", 
                                                data: [ { value: "0" }, { value: "0" }, { value: "1" }, { value: "0" }, ]
                                },
                                {
                                                seriesname: "Store 137", 
                                                data: [ { value: "0" }, { value: "10" }, { value: "12" }, { value: "80" }, ]
                                },
                                {
                                                seriesname: "Store 139", 
                                                data: [ { value: "40" }, { value: "50" }, { value: "2" }, { value: "2" }, ]
                                },
                ]
};
```

code use to get this

```
var res = JSON.parse(response);
var data_category = "";
var data_dataset = "";

$.each(res.weeks, function(i, item) {
                data_category += "{label: '"+item+"'}, ";
});


$.each(res.record, function(i, item) {
                data_dataset += '{seriesname: "Store '+i+'", data: [';
                                                                                $.each(item, function(x, rec) {
                                                                                                data_dataset += '{ value: "'+rec+'" }, ';
                                                                                });
                data_dataset += ']},';
});



const dataSource = {

                categories: [
                                {
                                                category: [
                                                                data_category
                                                ]
                                }
                ],

                dataset: [
                                data_dataset
                ]
};
```

there is no error , its just format for fusion chart issue

Comment: can you please fix the indendation ? 4 spaces for a level